# persistent or non persistent connection in testing web service

Tags: web-services, testing, connection-pooling, persistent-connection

I have a webservice. I am creating a test application to get response from this webservice. Added service reference to the web service application.

Logic in my test appplication is below.

```
for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
{
    MyServiceSoapClient wsClient = new MyServiceSoapClient();
    wsClient.Endpoint.Address = new EndpointAddress(serverAddress);
    MyLoginResponse loginResp=wsClient.Login("X","X");
}
```

Just wanted to know whether I am making a persistent connection or a non persistent connection in this approach. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Test your webservice using [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html). Pass curl the `-v` (verbose) flag. If you see `Connection: close` in the response header, your web service does *not* support persistent connections.